# Why is the for loop being skipped over?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to get an array of a certain row which is equal to the name, but for some reason the for loop is getting skipped over. I put a breakpoint, but the breakpoint never gets called.

```
 let query = PFQuery(className: "Tutors")
    query.whereKey("name", equalTo: self.name.text!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if(error == nil){
        for object in objects!{
            //placed break point on line below, program does not stop on breakpoint.
            let arr = object["Subject"] as? [String]

                self.subject = arr!

             print("subjects\(self.subject)")

            }
        }else{
            print(error)
        }
    })
```

Comment: Is it going to the else statement and printing an error? If not, did you check if objects is not empty? Try to print it out and see what you get

Comment: `objects`  must be empty. Is `error` definitely nil?

Comment: So it looks like objects is 0.

Comment: Why would it be 0. http://puu.sh/m5KCt/6fd6354aef.png

Comment: Are you sure the key is `name` and not `Name`?

Answer (score 0):

In your [parse dashboard](http://puu.sh/m5KCt/6fd6354aef.png) your column is named `Name`, while you are using `name` in `query.whereKey("name", equalTo: self.name.text!)`. Capitalize the key and you should be good.